# Auto-name files in SharePoint

Tags: office-365

**Problem:** We need a way to automatically rename files to a mandated construct en masse.

**Context:**  Our construct (mandated from on high) is:

1. Access Level (Unclassified, CUI)
2. Office Symbol
3. Meaningful Name
4. Date
5. Version

**Previously:**  We used a macro in Windows File Explorer to automatically change all closed file names within a folder.  We used a GUI for uses to manually select an access level and enter their Office Symbol.  We automatically used the 'dateModified' for 'Date' and "F" (i.e., Final) for the version.  We auto-separeated elements with a (*) and auto-replaced (spaces) with (*).

**Help:**  We need a way to automatically rename pre-existing file names in SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

https://zeitgeistcode.com/power-automate-rename-file-sharepoint/

you can change the trigger for "When a file was created" or "For a selected file".

If you want to rename more files at once, you can put this flow in a "each" loop.